# Writing an iterated integral of a function

Tags: calculus, integration

> Write an iterated integral of a function $f$ for the region $ x \ge 0, y \ge 0,$  between sinusoid $y = \sin x$ and line $y =\dfrac{2}{\pi}x$

I am stuck when trying to find the boundaries for my integrals. I think that the boundaries for $x$ are $ \displaystyle\int_{0}^{2π}$ because I only want to deal with one revolution, but when trying to find the boundaries for $y$, I cant find a solution for $\dfrac{2}{\pi}x = \sin(x)$. What is the correct approach for writing this iterated integral?

Answer (score 0):

$\sin x=\dfrac{2x}{\pi}$. For example $x=\dfrac{\pi}{2}$ works. Then $y=1$ would be a limit for that region.

[image]